# Hidden screens for sleep

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to stop a process then sleep for 10 seconds, kill off the next process sleep for 10 more seconds, then start a different process. The problem is everything runs at once. So the process that I want to start doesnt run because the others arent stopped yet.

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -windowstyle Minimized { Stop-Process -processname vpnagent -Force }
Start-Process powershell.exe -windowstyle Minimized { start-sleep -s 10 }
Start-Process Powershell.exe -windowstyle Minimized { Stop-Process -processname vpnui -force }
Start-Process powershell.exe -windowstyle Minimized { start-sleep -s 10 }
Start-Process -filepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe" -ArgumentList 'connect company.domain.com' -WindowStyle Minimized
```

Comment: Hi, the 4 first lines do not need `Start-Process` IMHO.

Comment: Is this a PowerShell script? Why are you starting the `powershell.exe` process for each line?

Comment: So that I can use the -windowstyle option.

Comment: not a big fan of the way you are running this but if all you need to do is wait for each command to complete before moving on to the next just use `-Wait`

Comment: @sodawillow why would you say I dont need the first four lines. The two processes must be stopped before I can start the last process.

Comment: @Mike Garuccio I'm open to suggestions. I'm only doing the way I know.

Comment: Just run it all within one script rather than creating a powershell script that then spawns a bunch more powershell processes that only do one thing each.  I get that you want the window minimized but you'll still have your main window showing up so I'm not sure what you gain with all the extra decorators

Comment: @MikeGaruccio do you have an example?

Comment: take a look at @sodawillow answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to propose this simpler code and explain what I meant:

```
Stop-Process -ProcessName vpnagent -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

Stop-Process -ProcessName vpnui -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

# (to make line shorter)
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"
$args = "connect company.domain.com"

Start-Process -FilePath $path -ArgumentList $args -WindowStyle Minimized
```

**EDIT** : this seems to do what you want, but you will see the first powershell window:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-File path/to/script.ps1" -WindowStyle Minimized
```

Comment: Thats what I had to begin with, the problem I found with this option was that the window would show to the user.

Comment: I would create a script to call another script?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution.

PowerShell script:

```
function StopProcess {
  param(
    $processName
  )
  $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
  if ( -not (Get-Process $processName) ) {
    return
  }
  Stop-Process $processName -Force
  while ( $true ) {
    if ( -not (Get-Process $processName) ) {
      break
    }
    Start-Sleep 5
  }
}

StopProcess vpnagent
StopProcess vpnui

$app = Join-Path ${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)} `
  "Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"
& $app "connect vpn.fabrikam.com"
```

Run the PowerShell script using a short executable I wrote called ExecGUI.exe (http://www.westmesatech.com/misctools.html):

```
ExecGUI -s 7 -- powershell.exe -File c:\pathtoscript\script.ps1
```

ExecGUI.exe is itself a GUI application and does not display a console window, so you can use it to execute powershell.exe itself in a minimized window (`-s 7`).